# Issues grouping in excel?

Tags: excel, grouping, pivot-table

I'm having a little bit of trouble grouping dates in excel. I have created a pivot table that groups a bunch of dates between 3 months together. However, I want to take advantage of the refresh ability of pivot tables--the idea in which when you refresh your pivot table, it will update to whatever you added or took away from the source of data your pivot table is based on.

However, when I grouped the dates between three months together, I noticed if I don't add a date that exactly corresponds to the dates within the grouping, the picot table does not add that entry into the pivot table. For example, if my grouping had the following dates (between May and July) in it:

```
5/21/2013, 7/18/2013, 6/8/2013
```

And in my source data spreadsheet had the following date added to it:

```
5/2/2013
```

`5/2/2013` would not be added to that specific grouping in the pivot table because it is not  exactly like the other dates as stated above. I want it so that I can group all dates from `5/1/2013` to `7/31/2013` inclusively as opposed to the dates in the original grouping. Would anyone have an idea on how to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provided your source 'dates' are not text Excel should be able to cope.

I fear (hope?) we were at cross-purposes about which "Group" to use. I meant the one that pops up (as on the left below) when right-clicking one of the `Qtr` headings in the PivotTable.

[image: SO17883636 example]

Comment: Hm, but I was not given the dialog that says Starting at: and ending at. What I did was I highlighted the columns that had the dates in them and clicked Group because I was not able to group them any other way. Every other way I tried I got something that said "Cannot group that section."

Comment: The dialog above only appears if all the values in the column are correctly interpreted as dates. If you have empty cells, or text, in the column this dialog won't appear. You will then have to group them by selecting a few of the values, but they will not be recognised as a range of dates, so the new values won't be inserted into a particular group.

Comment: @AndyG how do I know if they are correctly being interpreted as dates? I know they are right aligned meaning they are numbers and not text. I also have no blank columns when I group things together.

Comment: You can either right click some cells and choose `Format Cells` to see if a Date format is shown, or enter a formula in a cell `=A1+1` and see if it gives you the next day. If you confirm that all the dates are correct then I would probably delete the PT and rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: It does give me the next day indeed. I'll try to rebuild it and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @AndyG when grouping items, would you just right click one of the dates and then choose the range, or would you highlight all the items and then group them?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datawright.com.au/excel_resources/expanding_pivot_tables.htm

im curious as to how you are currently grouping them without adding new ones, there may be a way to work with what you already have especially if you are willing to incorporate some VBA

Comment: for example you could write a short macro that is triggered by the pivot tables refresh that does something a little more substantial

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to add additional formulas in the data you could just calculate "quarter" in an additional column (reference here)

[How can I obtain the year quarter from a date?](https://superuser.com/questions/101345/how-can-i-obtain-the-year-quarter-from-a-date)

I tend to always make my groups in the rows of data like this, rather than attempt it using pivot groups. For example, you might also extract "year" with = year(A1) in the rows - so you can easily add it as a pivot row item later for grouping. If your data source is properly formatted as an excel 2007 "table" these kind of formulas will fill themselves downward when you paste new data.

Comment: Understandable.. I've been working excel data a lot of years, I've got to say time and again I just went back to "tagging" the raw data rather than trying a fancy manipulation in the pivot table.. those calculations are better saved as formulas that have to divide (percentages, etc) that can't be pre-calculated at the row level.